# C# WebClient() Downloading a specific part of a website

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Ok I want to develop a scraping application to download specific text inside a div tag on a website. Lets take for example

```
<div class="main_content">WOTEVER GOES IN HERE, GOES IN HERE</div>
```

How would I go about downloading the text

> WOTEVER GOES IN HERE, GOES IN HERE

I understand I would need to use WebClient() with

```
.DownloadFile(sourceFileAddress, destinationFilePath);
```

Thankyou

Comment: Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Create a document using the downloaded source and you should be able to select the relevant parts easily. There are examples on the site.

Comment: Can HTML Agility Pack work with a site I do not own because on their site they say you need to upload the .dll file to my webserver. I want it so I can take articles from other website for later referencing for my computer course. I do not want to use bookmarks either because I have over 400. Would rather download the articles to .txt file then open them at a later date.

Comment: Yes. Add a reference to the dll file and use the library from your own code. You would only need to upload the dll file to your webserver if the code doing the download is running on your website.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are done on the "resource" basis and this resource is a file -> you can't download some text from a page, you need to download the file and parse it.

If the file is eg. very big and you know the div is at the beginning you may consider using TCP/IP sockets and handling the request and response manually (parsing on the fly), but I don't really know if that would give you any benefit.

Comment: You don't have to go quite to the tcp level - you can httpwebrequest/httpwebresponse to open a stream as well.